# Is there a regex where if first expression is valid then check for next

Tags: java, regex

For eg.

```
set "var" "value"
```

This will always be in the same order.

I am using `"(.+?)"` to get "var" and "value".

But I only want to match this only when it starts with "set".

```
base "as" "asd" - Should not match
set "as" "asd" - Match and return ("as", "asd")
```

Comment: `/set ("var") ("value")/`?

Comment: this will match the whole line. I just want var, value to match only if it starts with set.

Comment: What programming language (or regex flavor) are you using? It's important to mention that (and use the appropriate tags) when posting a regex question. Not all regex features are supported in all flavors.

Comment: Also, are the values you want to match (the ones enclose in quotations) always consecutive or can they appear anywhere in the string? Are there always two of them? Or an arbitrary number?

Comment: I am using Java and they will always be consecutive and only two matches.

Comment: If they're always two, then the easiest way would be to use `set "(.+?)" "(.+?)"` and find your values in the 1st and 2nd capturing groups. If they're more then two or you don't want to use multiple groups, you could use `(?<=set |\G )"(.+?)"`. Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/5khrEB/1).

Comment: Side note: it's usually better to use `"[^"]+"` instead of `".+?"` for a couple of reasons. One of which is that the latter would match `"""` while the former wouldn't.

Comment: You already know how to capture parts of regex but you seem to be unaware of how to access these groups, see the linked thread to learn about that.

Comment: Thanks this works for me  set "(.+?)" "(.+?)"